# How to improve one's bash/command-line skills?

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, command-line

Unfortunately I come from the Windows world and quite a newbie to Linux. I see people who are really productive due to their skills with BASH. Any pointers, tutorials, bools or suggestions to improve one's command-line skills? Something like http://www.commandlinefu.com/.

Comment: Try `bash tutorial` in your favorite search engine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out [superuser.stackexchange](https://superuser.com/) too, lots of good stuff there!

---

This is what I reference at least a few times a week:

[Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/)

And here is an actual [List of Bash online-tutorials](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/tutoriallist)!

I would also like to emphasize what @serk's answer says:

> Remove your GUI and you'll be forced to do everything via BASH

This is Very good advice! (and a well earned competing answer +1 vote ;)

In `/etc/inittab` change the runlevel to 3 from 5 and consequently you have to learn the shell because runlevel 3 means no GUI at all!

Answer (score 4):

Remove your GUI and you'll be forced to do everything via BASH. That will force you to do the same tasks via the command line that you would have normally done via the GUI.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to what's already been listed you can run `man <command>` to give you the "manual page" for a particular program.  These are usually pretty good.

Many people you likely work with have customized bash and tools like vim/emacs to varying degrees.  To see how people have customized things, you can go to their home directories and check out their "dot" files.  "dot" files are hidden so to view them you'll have to run:
`ls -a`

Standard "dot" files/directories:
.bashrc
.bash_profile
.vimrc
.screenrc
.inputrc

Common dot file names:
.alias(es)
.function(s)

People sometimes also write common scripts and put them in bin or scripts directories.

You can learn a TON of stuff by checking out what others have done.

If you are just checking out linux on your own, you can look for these types of files online.

Since you're coming from windows, you may be using cygwin.  If so, you can check out C:\cygwin\bin and C:\cygwin\usr\sbin for typical bash programs.  You can also use cygwin on windows in general to allow you to continue to use bash when using your windows computer.